# Loss Function NaN in deep learning model

Tags: python

I'm currently working on implementing a deep-learning model using binary data. While the model works fine with other binary datasets, I'm having issues with my own collected binary data. Specifically, the loss function is showing NaN values and the accuracy is consistently at the same value. I think the problem is with my data, not the model as my model is working fine with other data.

Here is my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import \
    Dense, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling1D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Input, Activation, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D, Conv1D, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, LSTM, Flatten, ELU, AveragePooling1D, Permute
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import Constant
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from keras import losses

import cvnn.layers as complex_layers
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss, categorical_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
        
def createSB_cart(inp_shape, classes_num, emb_size=64, weight_decay=1e-6, classification=False):
    convArgs = dict(use_bias=False,
                    kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay)
                    )
    tf.device("gpu:1")
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexInput(input_shape=inp_shape))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(256, 2, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same', **convArgs))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(2))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDropout(rate=0.2))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(256, 2, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same', **convArgs))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(2))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDropout(rate=0.2))


    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(128, 2, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same',**convArgs))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(2))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDropout(rate=0.2))


    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(128, 2, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same', **convArgs))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(2))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDropout(rate=0.2))

    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexConv1D(16, 2, activation='cart_leaky_relu', padding='same', **convArgs))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexAvgPooling1D(2))
    model.add(complex_layers.ComplexFlatten())
    if classification:
        model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDense(classes_num, activation='convert_to_real_with_abs',**convArgs))
    else:
        model.add(complex_layers.ComplexDense(classes_num, activation='linear', **convArgs))

    return model

model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_error, metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer="RMSprop")
```

Here's the output I'm seeing while fitting the model with my data:

```
Epoch 1/1000 101/101 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5023
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.49251, saving model to C:\Users\fafrin2\Downloads\radio\res_out\modelDir\IQ_model_our_day1_complex_after_fft_slices_5000_startIdx_0_stride_864_len_864_STFT_64.h5 101/101 [==============================] - 81s 792ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5023 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4925 Epoch 2/1000 101/101 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5019
Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.49251 101/101 [==============================] - 75s 743ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5019 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4925
```

The binary file I attached here:

[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1COTZabbdMkxFRB92eYDn_DXczuYPyXyX?usp=sharing)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked if your new data contains NaN values?  or if it's properly formatted?